# VBA - Add button on a userform: how to add its action

Tags: excel, vba, runtime, userform

In Excel, I'm adding buttons at runtime on a userform. How do I add these buttons actions to call a sub/function with parameters?

Here is how I currently add the button, which does not accept the 'OnAction' I add it

```
Dim MyR As Range, MyB As MSForms.Control

For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If (Len(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value) > 0) Then
        
        Set MyR = Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1))
        Set MyB = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
        
        With MyB
            .Name = i
            .Left = 50
            .Top = 25 * i
    
            .Caption = "Caption text"
            
            .OnAction = "SomeFunction"
            .Parameter = i
        End With
        
    End If
Next i
```

above code fails on the .OnAction, I can't find how to programmatically add an action here with a parameter different for each button?

**UPDATE**

Below partially works, but only the last event that has been set works, so only the last button is working as intended

```
Dim i As Integer
    Dim MyB As MSForms.Control
    Dim btnEvent As MyCustomButton
    
    For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If (Len(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value) > 0) Then
            
            Set MyB = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
            
            With MyB
                .Name = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
                .Caption = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
                .Left = 10
                .Top = 25 * i
                .Width = 75
                .Height = 20
                .Tag = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
            End With
            
            Set btnEvent = New MyCustomButton
            Set btnEvent.btn = MyB
            Set btnEvent.frm = UserForm1
            
            If (i > 4) Then 'TODO delete this loop
                Exit For
            End If
            
        End If
    Next i
    
    UserForm1.Show
```

**UPDATE 2**

Ok, it seems events need to be stored somewhere for them to work if you create multiple of them in a loop. Storing them in a collection solves it for me. Found this in: [Excel-VBA Capture all worksheet CommandButton click events to run universal code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687287/excel-vba-capture-all-worksheet-commandbutton-click-events-to-run-universal-code)

Thanks @Maciej Los for your help

If anyone find this usefull, bellow is my working module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub tests()
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MyB As MSForms.Control
    Dim btnEvent As MyCustomButton
    Dim colButtons As Collection
    
    Set colButtons = New Collection
    
    For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If (Len(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value) > 0) Then
            
            Set MyB = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
            
            With MyB
                .Name = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
                .Caption = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
                .Left = 10
                .Top = 25 * i
                .Width = 75
                .Height = 20
                .Tag = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
            End With
            
            Set btnEvent = New MyCustomButton
            Set btnEvent.btn = MyB
            Set btnEvent.frm = UserForm1
            colButtons.Add btnEvent
            
        End If
    Next i
    
    UserForm1.Show
    
End Sub
```

And the necessary class module:

```
Public WithEvents btn As MSForms.CommandButton
Public frm As UserForm

Private Sub btn_Click()
    Debug.Print (btn.Tag)
End Sub
```

A userform is needed too, named 'UserForm1' here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at here: [Assign on-click VBA function to a dynamically created button on Excel Userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566770/assign-on-click-vba-function-to-a-dynamically-created-button-on-excel-userform)

There you'll find a very well explained example provided by @598Bubblehead. The difference is that you want to pass parameter. I'd suggest to use `Tag` property of a custom button.

All you need to do is to:

- add class module and name it `MyCustomButton`

  ```
  Public WithEvents btn As MSForms.CommandButton
  Public frm As UserForm

  Dim iCount As Long

  Private Sub btn_Click()

    MsgBox "Parameter is: '" & btn.Tag & "'", vbInformation, "Welcome!"

  End Sub
  ```
- then use below code:

  ```
     Option Explicit

     Sub AddManyButtons()
         Dim ButCollection As New Collection
         Dim MyB As MSForms.Control
         Dim btnEvent As MyCustomButton
         Dim i As Integer

         For i = 1 To 5
             Set btnEvent = New MyCustomButton
             Set MyB = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
             With MyB
                 .Name = "DynamicButton" & i
                 .Caption = .Name
                 .Left = 10
                 .Top = 10 + ((i - 1) * 40)
                 .Width = 75
                 .Height = 32
                 .Tag = .Name
             End With

             Set btnEvent.btn = MyB
             Set btnEvent.frm = UserForm1
             ButCollection.Add btnEvent
             Set MyB = Nothing
         Next i
         UserForm1.Show
     End Sub
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Thanks @Maciej Los
Though if I loop through this, only the last assigned event triggers the 'btn_Click' sub


for example:

~~~
    For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            Set MyB = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
            
            With MyB
                .Tag = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
            End With
            
            Set btnEvent = New MyCustomButton
            Set btnEvent.btn = MyB
            Set btnEvent.frm = UserForm1
    Next i
~~~

Comment: You have to create as many button as many parameters you want to pass. Or, you have to pass a string then parse this  string into parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough, I added an update in the original post with the code used.
The problem is that only the last button works. Like if only 1 event is saved.
Sorry, I have never worked with events in VBA before and feel I am missing something

Comment: Aha, found the same solution elsewhere at the same time and edited my original post too. Thanks a lot for your help! Cheers!